# How to add a database to a jetty-server-embbeded app?

Tags: embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm using Jetty 9.2.11. and I embed Jetty in my Java SE application. I simply call it in my main method. Works great.

How can I add a jndi database that I can access with hibernate respectively reference with persistence.xml?

So far I followed the document of 9.2.11 www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jndi-datasource-examples.html

Subquestions?

- Does it require a web.xml or can I programmatically declare database?
  If yes, where do I put the web.xml?
- Where do I put the jdbc driver? In my case h2-1.4.187.jar
- Do I require a jetty.xml and a jetty-env.xml or can I programmatically declare all required settings?

In general, I do not understand the configuration differences between a regular Jetty Web Server or an embedded Jetty Server as I use it. The demarcation line is very blury - at least to me.

Thanks to any jetty guru.

Answer (score 2):

If found out myself after reading thoroughly thru the documentation and threads.

To answer my questions subsequently:

- Yes, in Jetty, everything that is possible to declare with xml can be pogrammed. Create a seperated and conventional war file and link to the path in the description. As in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888551/embedded-jetty-and-jndi-datasource-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-j)
- The JDBC driver belongs to the web server, the hibernate configuration to the web application. I used maven to "embed" the H2 driver in my java SE app. Use the persistence.xml to add the jndi to the server. e.g. jdbc/my_ds
- Yes, everything could be programmatically done.

As an alternative to pogrammatically declare all configurations settings, see this [blog post](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/setting-up-jndi-with-jetty-embedded.html).

Hope this helps out someone else.